# How can I retry a failed scrape with a different URL?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a functional scraper that scrapes a large number of websites from a database, and reads the results to the same database. I take the domain from the database, and manually append https://www. on the url. Even if this url is not correct, the vast majority of sites can redirect the spider correctly, but for some few sites, I get a DNSLookup error since there is no redirect in place, even though the site clearly exists and is accessible via a browser.

My question is, is there a way to retry a scrape that gets a DNSLookup error, but with a different URL? I am currently handling my errors in errback where I insert the necessary information to the database depending on what kind of an error I get. Is there a way to request a new scrape from the scrape results?

Comment: can you provide some code examples of what you've already tried? see guide on how to write a MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

When you yield Request to some url, besides `callback`, you can set `errback`, where you can catch such cases. In official documentation you can find pretty good example of its usage: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-response-ref-errbacks

```
def start_requests(self):
    for u in self.start_urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(u, callback=self.parse_httpbin,
                                errback=self.errback_httpbin,
                                dont_filter=True)

def errback_httpbin(self, failure):
    # log all failures
    self.logger.error(repr(failure))

    if failure.check(DNSLookupError):
        # this is the original request
        request = failure.request
        self.logger.error('DNSLookupError on %s', request.url)
```

And also check, maybe `RetryMiddleware` will fit your goals. Check official docs for `scrapy` here: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm afraid I was a bit unclear in my question though; I am using errback to catch errors already - what I am hoping for is to relaunch a scrape, from errback, with a different start_url than I had before. As I type this I realize it is a lot to ask and there probably is not an easy way to do it, but other alternatives require too much restructuring of the program for this time.